# Sci-fi book about an emergency response team using "portals" (doors? gates?) to fix ecological disasters?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find the name of a book I read a couple of years ago. I think it was pretty new at the time (mentioning mobile phones.) Here's what I can remember:

- Portals/"doors" are common, owned by a single corporation who provides a network around the globe.
- The portals are created via quantum entanglement, and can be "threaded" through one another during creation to make bigger and bigger portals "on site."
- The protagonist near the start of the book is part of an emergency response team which cleverly uses these portals to avert a disaster.
- Rich people have these doors from their homes to fancy rooms/domes on the moon.
- Some portals have been sent to "tap" the sun, which is used as "free" energy.
- Other portals have been sent out to mine asteroids.

IIRC all of this was set in "modern times," so I don't think it is the Commonwealth saga books by Peter Hamilton. For example, I have no recollection of anything to do with Mars.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This sounds very like [Salvation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34068552-salvation) by Peter F, Hamilton, which was published on September 4th 2018 so it fits with your memory of *a couple of years ago*.

The company that runs all the portals is *Connexion Corp*, and the portals are indeed created using quantum entanglement, and they are threaded through other portals.

The portals are used to provide power to starships from the Sun as you describe:

> Even so, starships require a phenomenal amount of thrust to accelerate up to a decent percentage of light speed, and Connexion Corp’s modern designs achieve in excess of eighty percent. Before Rindstrom, that would have required carrying vast amounts of energy and reaction mass on board. Now, all you do is drop a perfectly spherical portal into the sun. Meta-hot plasma slams into that hole at near-relativistic speed. At the same time, the portal’s exit is fixed at the apex of a magnetic cone, which channels the plasma into a rocket exhaust. There is no limit on how much plasma from the sun you can send through, and the starship masses very little—just the portal and its nozzle, guidance units, and a smaller portal communication link to mission control. It can accelerate fast.

The disaster is when a nuclear waste storage tank in Sweden gets blocked and the team leader *Callum Hepburn* uses a giant portal to swallow the whole tank.

Comment: There is a story early on within the novel about a team using a portal to deal with a blocked nuclear waste disposal system. The chapter is 'Callum and Yuri'.

Comment: @Michael ah, of course, thanks I'll put that in the answer.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much @JohnRennie! The blurb about the book doesn't mention anything about this, so I was unable to find it in my Amazon history.